# Using a form to generate values within other code

Tags: javascript, forms, input

I'd like people to be able to fill out a very simple, bare bones form with about 15-20 fields on it, and have those values populate into some pre-written HTML/CSS underneath, kind of like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21200339/convert-html-code-into-plain-text-inside-a-div-or-textarea)  (but with values from the form inside the code and without checkboxes).

I've had no problem finding simple text input forms that work for me, but I can't find a way to place those values into CSS text. I don't want to execute the CSS, just to show it underneath as plain text.

Ideally I'd like something like this in a form format:

Name: [text input box]
DOB: [text input box]
Home State: [text input box]
Other data: [text input box]
Other date: [text input box]

......

and then when they click 'Submit', this populates below as pure text so they can post the full code themselves:

```
<style type="text/css"> ... bunch of css </style>

<body>
<div class="">Name:</div> [inserted value from form]
<div class="">DOB:</div> [inserted value from form]
<div class="">Home State:</div> [inserted value from form]

other stuff
</body>
```

I should note that I'm using this within an existing forum (jcink), so I can't use php or anything involving multiple pages.  The most basic script that can take text input and regurgitate it as needed within pure text is what I need, but can't seem to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

SORRY, I wrote the answer while you where editing your question.
I'll post the java script answer later.

Since you are not specifying any restrictions on how to solve your situation, I recommend you use PHP, it will make it very easy for you.

So what you need is 2 files, one that captures the information and when you click submit it sends the information to new window which is just a PHP file that captures and processes the data of the form.

See the example here:
http://simplemx.net/StackOverflow/form.html
If this is what you are looking for, then continue reading to see the actions behind the php file.

But first, lest take a look a the form and take note of these 3 thing:

1.- The PHP **filename** that will be called when you press submit, the file name goes in the **action** attribute.

> `<form ... action="show-data.php" ...`

2.- The form method, in this case we will use **POST**

> `<form ... method="POST">`

3.- Each input field has its own unique **name** attribute, that must not contain spaces and take in mind they are case-sensite when you use them in PHP

> `<input type="text"  name="home_state"\>`

HTML file example:

```
<form id="formulario" action="show-data.php" method="POST">
    Name: <input type="text"  name="name"   required><br>        
    DOB: <input type="text"  name="dob"  required><br>
    Home State: <input type="text"  name="home_state" ><br>                  
    <input  type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

AND the PHP file that captures and displays the data from the example:

```
<?php 
// put the information from the form in variables
$name = $_POST['name'];
$dob = $_POST['dob'];
$home_state = $_POST['home_state'];

// put the variables into a string with HTML format 
$html = <<<HTML
<div class="">Name: $name</div> 
<div class="">DOB: $dob</div> 
<div class="">Home State: $home_state</div>
HTML;

// print the string with the HTML
echo $html;
?>
```

This can also be done in one single file or with JavaScript.

If this is not what you are looking for, please provide more details and examples of you problem or situation you are trying to solve.

PS: if you don't have a server to test PHP files, there are many free php web hosting companies out there, so you can play/test your work.

Comment: If you can use jQuery, it is also simple.
1.- Get all the values of the input fields.

Comment: 2.- for the string that will go inthe the url in POST format  
3.- Open a new page(window)  
4.- In the New window extract the data from the url  
5.- Using jQuery populate (set) all the info wher it is supposed to go.

Comment: Okay, so I figured out how to make this work by putting the html on the forum page, and having it go to the .php form hosted elsewhere.  It's not ideally what I wanted (as I'd still like to use javascript and just have it populate below), but it works and that's what's most important. 

The issue I still have is that it's formatting the code I put into the form, rather than showing it as plain text.  I.E. I want them to literally see <b>Name:</b>, *not* to see the word name in bold.  Is there a way to do that?  

Thank you!!

Comment: Ha!  I threw textarea tags around it and it worked!  It's not pretty, but it does the job. Thank you docliving.